# how to import linux command in shell script file as  the value of a variable ?

Tags: shell, command

I am using `Fedora 10`. If I write `java -version` in terminal, it gives me java version. I want to write a shell script file to check whether the java version is greater than 1.5.
The main problem is that I donot know how to assign the value of `java -version` command as to a variable of `shell script`.
How to create shell script file for that ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use backticks:

```
JAVA_VERSION=`java-version`
```

Comment: can i confirm you did get a result in JAVA_VERSION variable?

Answer (score 4):

As answered above, you can use backticks or (if your keyboard doesn't have them) use the following format:

`JAVA_VERSION=$(command)`

Answer (score 1):

you should direct stderr to stdout

```
$ var=$(java -version 2>&1)
$ set -- $var
$ echo $3
"1.6.0_0"
$ echo ${3//[._\"]/}
1600
```

Now you can compare $ver to see if its greater than 1500.

Answer (score 0):

All the above Answer will work for you. below are the common example which you can use to get the value of variable:

```
JAVA_VERSION=`java-version` or JAVA_VERSION="java-version" or JAVA_VERSION=$(command)
```

The way is to set the value of variable is many. You can use your easiest way to fulfill your requirement. Like I'm using

```
var=$(awk -F'"' '/^variable=/ {print $2}' script1.sh )
echo $var
```